# Concurent foreach iteration of two list strings

Tags: c#, list, foreach

Let's say I have *two* `List<string>`. These are populated from the results of reading a text file

List **owner** contains:

```
cross
jhill
bbroms
```

List **assignee** contains:

```
Chris Cross
Jack Hill
Bryan Broms
```

---

During the read from a SQL source (the SQL statement contains a join)... I would perform

```
    if(sqlReader["projects.owner"] == "something in owner list" || sqlReader["assign.assignee"] == "something in assignee list")
    {
       // add this projects information to the primary results LIST
       list_by_owner.Add(sqlReader["projects.owner"],sqlReader["projects.project_date_created"],sqlReader["projects.project_name"],sqlReader["projects.project_status"]);

       // if the assignee is not null, add also to the secondary results LIST
       // logic to determine if assign.assignee is null goes here 

       list_by_assignee.Add(sqlReader["assign.assignee"],sqlReader["projects.owner"],sqlReader["projects.project_date_created"],sqlReader["projects.project_name"],sqlReader["projects.project_status"]);
    }
```

I do not want to end up using nested foreach.

The FOR loop would probably suffice. Someone had mentioned ZIP to me but wasn't sure if that would be a preferable route to go in my situation.

Comment: By `iterate through both lists` do you mean compare *only* the first item in `alpha` with the first item in `beta`, then the second item with the second, and so forth? If so, just use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Have you considered just using `LINQ`'s `.Contains`? (like 'alpha.Contains(result["chestA.item"]))` Or am I misunderstanding your check? It doesn't seem like any nesting is necessary at all. Maybe you'd have two loops in a row, but that's just `O(2*n)`, which is still `O(n)`.

Comment: This feels like it needs some clarification.  You have two lists of the same size and you want to do *what* with them, exactly?  What are you reading from the SQL source?  What are you trying to do with your lists?  Are you saying you are getting a pair of items (A and B) and you are trying to see if (A) is in list alpha OR (B) is in list beta?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I added some clarification (hopefully helps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One loop to iterate through both lists (assuming both have same count):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Count; i++)
    {
        var itemAlpha = alpha[i] // <= your object of list alpha
        var itemBeta = beta[i] // <= your object of list beta
        //write your code here
    }
```

Comment: +1. Don't make things more complicated than they have any need to be.

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe, you don't need to iterate at all.

This is what you need:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx

Usage:

```
if ((listAlpga.contains(resultA) || (listBeta.contains(resultA)) {
   // do your operation
}
```

List Iteration will happen implicitly inside the `contains` method. And thats 2n comparisions, vs n*n for nested iteration.

You would be better off with sequential iteration in each list one after the other, if at all you need to go that route.

Comment: Note that `Contains`, internally, will be iterating the data structure.  You don't need to *explicitly* iterate it.

Comment: Also note if you had a more complex object than string, you could overload the contain function of the object.

Comment: Or use `FirstOrDefault` where you can use whatever predicate you want, and then check if the result is null (i.e. has not been found) - or use it if `FirstOrDefault` finds it.

Comment: Oops I was editing to make the implicit iteration more explicit while you typed the comment. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

This list is maybe better represented as a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` which would pair the two list values together in a single list.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options for this. The least "painful" would be plain old `for` loop:

```
for (var index = 0; index < alpha.Count; index++)
{
    var alphaItem = alpha[index];
    var betaItem = beta[index];

    // Do something.
}
```

Another interesting approach is using the indexed LINQ methods (but you need to remember they get evaluated lazily, you have to consume the resulting enumerable), for example:

```
alpha.Select((alphaItem, index) => 
{
    var betaItem = beta[index];

    // Do something
})
```

Or you can enumerate both collection if you use the enumerator directly:

```
using (var alphaEnumerator = alpha.GetEnumerator())
using (var betaEnumerator = beta.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (alphaEnumerator.MoveNext() && betaEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var alphaItem = alphaEnumerator.Current;
        var betaItem = betaEnumerator.Current;

        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) (if you need pairs) or [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) (if you need combined list) are possible options to iterate 2 lists at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I like doing something like this to enumerate over parallel lists:

```
int alphaCount = alpha.Count ;
int betaCount  = beta.Count  ;
int i = 0 ;

while ( i < alphaCount && i < betaCount )
{
  var a = alpha[i] ;
  bar b = beta[i] ;
  // handle matched alpha/beta pairs
  ++i ;
}

while ( i < alphaCount )
{
  var a = alpha[i] ;
  // handle unmatched alphas
  ++i ;
}

while ( i < betaCount )
{
  var b = beta[i] ;
  // handle unmatched betas
  ++i ;
}
```